# Setting Up Google Hangout Deep Links

Tags: ios, deep-linking, google-hangouts

I'm running into issues getting Deep Links to work in the Google Hangout's app on iOS. When a link, which works in other social media apps (ex: Facebook), is shared to the Google Hangouts app, later clicking it within the Google Hangout app redirects it to the browser and then the app's App Store page, regardless of the fact that the app to which it should be Deep Linking is already installed on the device.

Is there a resource available describing the process of setting up Deep Links in Google Hangouts? I know there are specific meta tags which are required to get Deep Link sharing working properly for Facebook and Twitter. Is there something similar required for Google Hangouts?

Hoping someone with experience in this area can point me in the right direction go get this feature working.

Comment: Are you using Universal Links? How are you redirecting to AppStore? Can you share your link?